# Are spell casting levels determined as character levels or class levels when multi-classing?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

As an example, A level 6 bard multi classes to a level 1 Cleric; does the bard have the spell slots that come with level 7 (Being 1 4th level spell slot) or would the bard have to wait until they level into level 7 before getting that spell slot?

Comment: Have you read multiclassing section of the PHB?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help me a whole lot, I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 9):

When you multiclass you are a level 6 Bard and a level 1 Cleric.

> You determine your available spell slots
>   by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric,
>   druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, half your levels
>   (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes, and
>   a third of your fighter or rogue levels (rounded down)
>   if you have the Eldritch Knight or the Arcane Trickster
>   feature. Use this total to determine your spell slots by
>   consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table.

6 bard + 1 cleric = 7 spellcaster levels

7th Level: 4 1st, 3 2nd, 3 3rd, and 1 fourth.

Now, you might not know any fourth level spells, but even if you don't you can spend that slot to cast lower level spells at the fourth level -- possibly taking advantage of a spell that has greater effect when cast "at higher level".